# Hadoop Distributed File system

Tags: hadoop

I have a file.txt that has 3 blocks (block a , block b, block c). How does hadoop write these blocks in to Cluster.. My question is Does hadoop follow parallel write? Or does block b  has to wait for block a to  write into cluster? Or block a and block b and block c are parallely writtten in to hadoop cluster...

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you meant by 'blocks' ?

Comment: file.txt is divided in blocks .. here  file.txt is divided in to three blocks . say for example  the size of file.txt is  192 MB then that file.txt will be divided into 3 blocks eac of 64 MB

Answer (score 5):

When you copy a file **from the local file system to HDFS** or **when you create a new file in HDFS**: blocks are copied sequentially - first, the first block is copied to a datanode, then the second block is copied to a datanode and so on.

What is done in parallel, however, is replica placement: while a datanode receives data of the block from the client, the datanode saves the data in a file, which represents the block, and, simultaneously re-sends the data to another datanode, which is supposed to create another replica of the block.

When you copy a file **from one location to another location inside a HDFS cluster or between two HDFS clusters**: you do it in parallel using DistCp.

Comment: So Are you saying that from local file system to HDFS  writing the replication of  single block(block a) to other data nodes is done parallely and writing the block a to a data node  and block b a datanode is done sequentially?

Answer (score 1):

**WHEN YOU ATTEMPT TO COPY A FILE OR CREATE A NEW FILE FROM A LOCAL SYSTEM TO ANY HDFS: THE BLOCKS ARE COPIED AS A SEQUENCE OF DATA-NODES, THIS IS VERY SIMILAR TO THAT IN AN ARRAY. THIS IS CONSECUTIVE-SEQUENTIAL ARRANGEMENT OF DATA-BLOCKS.**

When this handshake is taking place, the moment the datanode receives the first request, this *gets replicated to a file, creating a SAVEPOINT* and then the same process occurs sequentially for the other blocks, which makes it redundant and the saved state is used for comparison.

Whereas when you copy the file from one segment to the other inside the same block or between two different blocks you use **AHDC** (Apache Hadoop DistCp).

Hadoop is designed to keep the data state restored till the transaction has been completed.

Comment: So in this case the block b has to wait until the block a gets written into HDFS ? Am i right?

Comment: yes being a sequential copy mechanism, you will have to